# Bootstrap 5 + Vue3: How to remove all Tooltip Instances beforeUnmount?

Tags: tooltip, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

When my Vue3 component is mounted on a specific site i instantiate all my Bootstrap5 Tooltips.

```
const tooltipTriggerList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
tooltipTriggerList.forEach(tooltipTriggerEl => {
  return new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

[image: Console Log of Tooltip Instances]

When i don't clear those Instances beforeUnmounting the component the Tooltip stays visible. So i need to remove all Tooltips before that.

```
  beforeUnmount () {
   const tooltips = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip'))
    tooltips.forEach(el => {
     el.remove()
    })
  }
```

I don't feel like this is the proper way of deleting those Instances. My main problem is that i don't have any clue how to target the created Instances of BS5 Tooltips (console.log).

My question is: How do i dispose those Instances with the built in Bootstrap5 functions?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#dispose

Answer (score 0):

To remove the created Tooltips instances you need to store them somewhere when you create them so that you can access them and hide/destroy them whenever you want.

So basically do this:

```
const tooltipTriggerList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
const arrayOfTooltipsInstances = [];
tooltipTriggerList.forEach(tooltipTriggerEl => {
  let tooltipInstance = new Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
  arrayOfTooltipsInstances.push(tooltipInstance); // You could also do a one-liner here instead of assigning the instance to a variable, but I kept it like this to keep it more readable
})
```

And when you want to dispose of them, for example, do:

```
arrayOfTooltipsInstances.forEach(tooltipInstance => {
  tooltipInstance.dispose();
});
```